# How to pass parameter from bash and string comparison in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

How to pass a parameter to awk to compare the string with pipe input?
For example, followings are used to filter files created before Aug 2011 under specific folder

```
#!/bin/bash
$FILTER_DIR=$1

# file date before it should be listed.
FILTER_BEFORE="2011-08"

# $6 in awk statement is date of file name($8)
find $1 -type f | \
    sed 's/^/ls -l /g' | \
    sh | \
    awk ' if ( $6 le $FILTER_BEFORE ) { print $8 }'
```

The result list all files under $FILER_DIR without filtering.
It seems AWK didnot receive $FILTER_BEFORE from bash properly.
Any comment is appreciated!!

Comment: `le` is Perl, not awk: `awk -v "fb=$FILTER_BEFORE" '$6 <= fb {print $8}'`

Answer (score 4):

if using gawk, pass it as a parameter

```
find $1 -type f | 
sed 's/^/ls -l /g' | 
sh | 
awk -v filter_before=${FILTER_BEFORE} '{ if ( $6 <= filter_before ) { print $8 } }'
```

Comment: I never knew about this feature. Spectacular!

Comment: +1. However, you don't need the backslash line-escapes for lines ending with a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use double quotes and escape the other AWK variables so they don't get interpreted by bash.

```
find $1 -type f | \
    sed 's/^/ls -l /g' | \
    sh | \
    awk " if ( \$6 le \"$FILTER_BEFORE\" ) { print \$8 }"
```

Alternatively you can break out just the variable into double quotes so you can avoid escaping.

```
find $1 -type f | \
    sed 's/^/ls -l /g' | \
    sh | \
    awk ' if ( $6 le "'"$FILTER_BEFORE"'" ) { print $8 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
touch -t 201107302359 30_july_2011
find . -type f ! -newer 30_july_2011
```

Or this (*GNU find* only):

```
find . -type f ! -newermt '2011-07-30 23:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following statements seem work properly.
Thanks for everybody's help.

```
find $1 -type f | \ 
sed 's/^/ls -l /g' | \ 
sh | \ 
awk -v filter_before=${FILTER_BEFORE} '{ if ( $6 < filter_before ) { print $8 } }'
```